# What is the variable's name of the total amount of the order (Back-office prestashop 1.7.5)?

Tags: php, variables, orders, prestashop-1.7, backoffice

back-office side, I'm looking (and I can not find ) the name of the variable php where there is the total amount TTC of the order (in order's table) ...

I can look in cart.php, AdminOrdersController.php, I can not find ...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends where you are, but otherwise with a command id you can find it by doing :

```
$order = New Order($id_order);
echo $order->total_paid;
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks !
In fact, i'm trying to add a new price to products, but idk where it's best to do so. At the creation of cart ? order ? ....

Comment: Yes in in cart !

Comment: What do you mean @ethercreation ? In Cart.php ? Also, do you know what's the template of the cart's page back-office side ?